# TexWorks destroys tex document when compiling with pdfLaTex

Tags: pdftex, texworks

When I input

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  Hello World!
\end{document}
```

and compile with pdfLaTex, the output .pdf file is created and looks good. My sourcefile doesn't.

[image: .]

Comment: Well don't name your tex file pdf! You are overwriting your file with the generated pdf.

Comment: As already noted, that's a PDF if viewed as a text file: you got a very badly chosen file name.

Comment: helgso, the source file (with the `tex` extension) and the file produced (a `pdf` or a `div`) are two different things! From `myfile.tex`, (pdf)latex will produce a file called `myfile.pdf`. I find this mistake rather funny.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: I knew it was something as simple as that. You can't google this stuff! Thank you guys haha

Answer (score 4):

Output overwriting input...

In this case, it is obvious what happens because of using the output extension for the input extension.  In olden times, one rather subtle but quite dreadful mistake you could commit was writing

```
\include{chapter1.tex}
```

which resulted in LaTeX writing auxiliary data on a file `chapter1.tex.aux` which the DOS file system abbreviated to `chapter1.tex` which was then gone.

Later versions of emTeX were smarter about what file names it would overwrite, and when it would refuse.  But this trap was present in several DOS-based TeX distributions.

I'm still somewhat surprised by TeXWork's behavior: I'd have expected `LaTex.pdf` (cough cough) to be compiled into `LaTex.pdf.pdf` without conflict.  Or at least, like emTeX in olden times learnt to do, to refuse overwriting the original file.  I almost fear that this behavior could result in resuscitating the above-mentioned age-old `\include` catastrophe.

Comment: Well, try making a file `test.pdf` with contents `Hello, World! \bye` and run `pdftex test.pdf`. It will say at the end: `Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 12037 bytes).` This has nothing to do with TeXworks, this is simply `pdftex`'s default behaviour: it expects user to know better than mess with the extensions so badly ;)

Comment: The output filename is calculated by the tex engine not by the texworks editor, web2c tex has always discarded the extension and appended its output extension so you can have for example `myfile.ltx` for latex files, producing `myfile.dvi`